# Date value in JS results in 12/31/1969 4:00 PM

Tags: javascript

I have the following code snippet which is giving me fits. I just want to fetch the latest date, instead I get 12/31/1969 4:00 PM.  Code is below, any/all help greatly appreciated.

```
if (setPass) {

    var lastDate = new Date().toJSON();
        for (var k = passVal.Values.length - 1; k >= 1; k--) {
            if (passVal.Values[k].Average !== passVal2.Values[k].Average) {
                lastDate = passVal.Values[k].Date.toUTCString();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    var passView = {

        ID: id,
        lastDate: lastDate
    };

    results.push(passView);
}
```

Comment: Is there any other code to go with this, and also does this occur in all browsers?

Comment: this is the only code that invokes the date.  it happens in all browsers

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle to be able to reproduce this on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format you need that is a String, So you you can build your own one. Like,

```
var date = new Date().getDate() < 10 ? '0' + new Date().getDate() : new Date().getDate();
var month = new Date().getMonth() < 10 ? '0' + new Date().getMonth() : new Date().getMonth();
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var fullYear = month +'/'+ date  +'/'+ year ;
console.log(fullYear);
```

then you can pass it. Cheers :).

Comment: you can have a variable storing new Date() and use it. That's better, coz it will reduce execution time. Thanks.